# onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) Method

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
   FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Selected", ((Car) event.getObject()).getModel());
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

I need to know the following:

1. When I click on a Row, will this method be called?
2. Can I display the rows content using this method?

See: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/webapp/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.xhtml?r=3293

Answer (score 1):

This PrimeFaces Showcase example fully covers these cases:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf

To answer your questions:

1. Yes.
2. Yes. Set a `car` attribute in your bean inside this method. Make sure getters and setters are available for your `car`. Display the `car` on your page using an Ajax PPR when the row select event happens.

The code in the showcase example I referenced has all the pieces you need to do this.